# Is Ianto gay in Torchwood?

Tags: sexuality, torchwood

It is pretty clear in the series that Ianto has *feelings* for Jack, but it seems that Jack never returns the feelings. Jack's romantic stress with Gwen also appears to get in the way of the relationship that Ianto seems to desire.

**Is there any evidence that Ianto actually has a homosexual relationship with Jack?**

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ianto_Jones

Comment: What's the actual question here? Are you asking whether Ianto was gay (as in the title) or whether he had a relationship with Jack (as in the body of the question)? Those are two completely different questions, and they may well have (in fact, they do seem to have) opposite answers.

Comment: Everybody is gay in Torchwood. Even the monsters are quite gay.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, Ianto had a sexual relationship with Jack for much of the series; he was considered Jack's main romantic interest. Their relationship was not secret; Owen, for example, often claimed to feel like the only Torchwood member without a partner (Jack & Ianto, Gwen & Rhys, Tosh & Tommy) and Jack has kissed Ianto on-screen many times. Ianto once claimed that their relationship was "more than just sex", though it's not always clear what Jack's motivations are in any relationship.

As far as I know, this was Ianto's one and only homosexual relationship, but there's a lot of supplemental material about Torchwood that I've never read. While on the show, we certainly don't see any serious relationship develop between Ianto and anyone else.

Comment: In Torchwood Children of Earth, Ianto tells his sister something along the lines of "It's not men.  It's just him."  That means that Jack is Ianto's only male lover, provided Ianto is telling the truth.

Comment: Wasn't Ianto also in love with The Cyberwoman (Lisa)? I guess that would make him bi-sexual. It's been a while since I've seen that episode, but main thing I remember was all the bawling he did when they had to disable/kill her. He was all waterworks in that episode.

Answer (score 3):

This is directy addressed by Ianto in [Torchwood: Children of Earth - Day One](http://www.chakoteya.net/Torchwood/301.htm).

> **IANTO:** *It's weird. It's just different. **It's not men, it's just him. It's only him.** And I don't even know what it is, really, so. So
> I'm not broadcasting it.*

Out in the real world, the actor who portrays Ianto, Gareth David-Lloyd, is pretty keen on the concept of "fluid sexuality" so the idea that Ianto isn't *completely gay (or even bisexual)* isn't something that offends his sensibilities.

> **AE:** **When we last talked to you about Ianto, you described him as bisexual. When you got the script for Children of Earth, *was that the
> first time you’d heard Ianto’s particular take on his relationship
> with Jack as Ianto not being gay per se?***
>
> **GDL:** *Yeah, I mean, Jack is the first gay man in Ianto’s life. He didn’t know what was there. **I think it’s meant to highlight the fact
> that it’s not necessarily a man or woman that attracts you, it’s the
> whole package.** It’s not always black or white, straight or gay. It
> could be the same sex.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Interview with Torchwood’s Gareth David-Lloyd](http://www.newnownext.com/interview-with-torchwoods-gareth-david-lloyd/02/2008/)</sup></sub>

In an interview with Gay Times, both Barrowman and Lloyd-Jones were at pains to stress that Ianto isn't confused sexually, he's simply not defined by classic concepts of sexual identity.

> ***"Ianto is not confused, but he's fallen in love with a man,"** Barrowman
> explains. **"He never saw himself as being gay, but for the first time
> he's fallen in love with a man. It's something new that's happened to
> him. His sister raises the issue. She's like, 'We don't care. Do you
> like him? Are you happy?' So he's more worried about it himself, which
> is true of a lot of gay men.** They're more worried about telling people
> when other people actually don't give a shit. And that's the beauty, I
> think, of that scene.*
>
> *"That's what Russell does beautifully. Jack, he's omnisexual in his
> time period, but if it was today you'd say he was gay or bisexual or
> whatever, but the thing with Ianto, which I think is great, is that
> there are people out there like that. They're sexual, they don't
> define themselves. And I'm not saying that you shouldn't define
> yourself because you know me, I stand up for the boys and the girls
> and all the rights, but there are some people out there who do stuff
> in their bedroom which is very much like what gay men and women do,
> but it doesn't make them gay, because they're with a woman. If that
> makes any sense."*
>
> <sub><sup>[GAY TIMES JUNE 09 INTERVIEW WITH JOHN BARROWMAN AND GARETH DAVID-LLOYD](http://phaetonschariot.livejournal.com/14872.html)</sup></sub>

And for the record, yes, they're actively engaged in a sexual relationship.